# React Native 31, New Appdelegate.m no localhost to change : Network Request Failed

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I just upgraded to latest version (31) of react-native, my app which was working, is not working anymore. everytime i get Network Request Failed error from fetch.

AppDelegate.m is changed and there is no localhost or 127.0.0.1 to change.

is it placed somewhere else?

AppDelegate.m :

```js
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"OpenCampus"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

or should i change RCTWebSocketExecutor.m ?

```js
if (!_url) {
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger port = [standardDefaults integerForKey:@"websocket-executor-port"] ?: 8081;
    NSString *host = [[_bridge bundleURL] host];
    if (!host) {
      host = @"localhost";
    }
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%zd/debugger-proxy?role=client", host, port];
    _url = [RCTConvert NSURL:URLString];
  }

  _jsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.facebook.react.WebSocketExecutor", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  _socket = [[RCTSRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:_url];
  _socket.delegate = self;
  _callbacks = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  _injectedObjects = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  [_socket setDelegateDispatchQueue:_jsQueue];

  NSURL *startDevToolsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/launch-js-devtools" relativeToURL:_url];
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:startDevToolsURL] delegate:nil];

  if (![self connectToProxy]) {
    RCTLogError(@"Connection to %@ timed out. Are you running node proxy? If "
                 "you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP "
                 "address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`.", _url);
    [self invalidate];
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. "Allow Arbitrary Loads" was removed from info.plist somehow. it should be added to info.plist and value should be "YES" otherwise app cannot access internet.

More info : [React-Native fetch, Network request failed. not using localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077273/react-native-fect-network-request-failed-not-using-localhost)